# How to save data child view that is call by java-script?

Tags: javascript, yii

I renderPartial rendered two child view(_sectiohead.php and _classtecher.php) in my create.php like this

[image]

but i can't save date to db because create button not submit data to my action-create method how can i solve this ?

*in my _sectionhead.php (same button added to _classtecher.php)*

[image]

*in my create.php i add script and renderPartial _sectionhead.php and _classtecher.php

renderPartial

[image]

script*

[image]

Need quick help  thank you

Answer (score 1):

Render partial the _sectionHead on _classTeacher before the submit button.

```
//On _classTeacher.php
/** 
 *
 *  Other codes on _classTeacher.php
 */

<?php
   $this->renderPartial('_sectionHead',array('model'=>$model));
 ?>

 // then your submit button
 <div class="row button">
     <?php echo CHtml:submitButton($model->isNewRecord() ? 'Create' : 'Update'); ?>
 </div>
```

Then catch it in your controller

Comment: no i need to submit if the user select the add teacher (_classteacher child view),i need to submit that from data to db.

Answer (score 0):

if you renderPartial after the form opening ($this->form) or put the beginning in the first part and form ending in the second part, you can catch every thing in between!

it's that simple..

and if you want to submit your inputs to another somewhere other than default, you can put another button and give it a submit url, or use jquery to serialize thepart you want to be send, and using ajax, get the answer . like:

```
$.ajax({
        url :'<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/controller/action/' ?>' ,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { ... } )
.done(function(){
```

do some thing here ...

});